# Rails 4: Bootstrap-sass and glyphicons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using the bootstrap-sass gem, but can't get glyphicons to show up in my view.

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 4.0.0'
```

CSS File

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

View

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap 2.3+ you need `<i class="icon-indent-right"></i>`.

Check the [official guide](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons).

Comment: Gah! I googled the bootstrap API and it's different than the one you linked. /wrists

Answer (score 3):

try to use

CSS File

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; //this allow the gliphicon to work
@import "bootstrap";
```

This worked with my Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```